# Class - namespace and template member function specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I have this code:

In A.h

```
namespace MyUtils 
{
    class A 
    {
       public:
          A();
          ~A();

         template <typename T> Set(T val);
         template <typename T> Set(T * val);

    }

    template <typename T>
    void A::Set(T * val)
    {

    }
}
```

In A.cpp, I have this

```
using namespace MyUtils;

template <>
void A::Set<int>(int val)
{
}

template <>
void A::Set<char *>(char * val)
{

}
```

This kind of logic compiles OK In MSVC or in Xcode. But on Linux, using gcc (g++), I got

> error: specialization of ‘template void MyUtils::A::Set(T)’
>   in different namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug in MSVC and Xcode.

From 14.7.2 Explicit instantiation:

> An explicit instantiation shall appear in an enclosing namespace of
>   its template.

Comment: And can you give me hint, how to correct it ? I have tried template<> void MyUtils::A::Set<int>(int val) ...but same problem

Comment: @MartinPerry Surround it with namespace MyUtils { ... } - you might drop using namespace MyUtils; also

Comment: @MartinPerry: Declare them in the header file, inside the namespace; then your definitions should be fine. (They must be declared there, otherwise other translation units will use the generic template, not your specialisations).

Answer (score 0):

I also consider this as a bug because according to the C++ Standard ( section 14.7.3 Explicit specialization )

> 2 An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace
>   enclosing the specialized template. An explicit specialization whose
>   declarator-id is not qualified shall be declared in the nearest
>   enclosing namespace of the template, or, if the namespace is inline
>   (7.3.1), any namespace from its enclosing namespace set. Such a
>   declaration may also be a definition. If the declaration is not a
>   definition, the specialization may be defined later (7.3.1.2).

So you should use the fully qualified name

```
template <>
void MyUtils::A::Set<int>(int val)
{
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, but error was the same. Solution from @Dieter worked